# IOS Background Gradients - Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Is there anyway to show background gradients on the storyboard instead of firing up the simulator every-time to see what it looks like

I've created and extension

```
import UIKit

extension CAGradientLayer {

    func stopwatchColour() -> CAGradientLayer {

        let topColour = UIColor(red: (11/255.0), green: (128/255.0), blue: (105/255.0), alpha: 1)
        let bottomColour = UIColor(red: (39/255.0), green: (90/255.0), blue: (78/255.0), alpha: 1)
        let gradientColours: [CGColor] = [topColour.cgColor, bottomColour.cgColor]
        let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]
        let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = gradientColours
        gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]
        return gradientLayer
    }
}
```

Then from my controller

```
    let background = CAGradientLayer().stopwatchColour()
    background.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, at: 0)
```

Comment: Look into `IBInspectable` and `IBDesignable` - you can create custom subclasses that will display - and be editable - in storyboard / Interface Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend trying the code in a swift playground. Swift Playground executes your code every time you type. You can see what your background looks like and edit it however you wish. Then you can paste your code into your Xcode project without having to run the simulator.

Good luck